# How to add the SSL certificate in Eclipse to hit SoapUI webservice?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ssl, soapui

The SoapUI webservices I'm having are client secured with .p12 and .cer formats.
When I hit the request from Eclipse, I'm  getting the following console error.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
```

Following is my code.

```
public class ClientService {
    public static String webServiceURL = "URL";
    public static String requestXMLPath = "Path for request xml";
    public static String response="";

    @Test
    public void clientMethod() throws IOException, Throwable{
        String methodname = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
        String request = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(requestXMLPath)));

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(webServiceURL); 
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try{
            post.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/soap+xml,application/dime,multipart/related,text/*"); 
            RequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(request.toString(), "text/xml", "utf-8");         
            post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);           
            client.executeMethod(post);         
            response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();  
            System.out.println(post.getStatusCode()+"\n"+post.getStatusLine()+"\n"+post.getStatusText());
            String xmlformatresponse = response.replace("><", ">\n<");
            System.out.println("Response is "+xmlformatresponse);

        } 
        catch( Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

 }

}
```

As the webservice is client secured, I need to import the SSL certificate into Eclipse. 
Could anyone provide the solution.

Comment: How would some reproduce the above exception? reproducible steps are appreciated.

Comment: I've Java code to hit the soap request where we need to provide wsdl path and request path. When I used the same code to hit the client webservice, I'm getting this error.

Comment: So, put your code which is used by editing the question.

Comment: Hi @Rao I added the code. Please refer to it